# capacitance sensor between humans

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance

I am using this module: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1374

My idea is to sense a person wearing this module and when touched by another person, the LED lights up. I read numerous articles and Googled around and have a little understanding of how this could work.

The module works such that when it is powered it gets a "zero state" then when the touch pad is touched it turns the LED on, when my hand is on the sensor (since I will be wearing the touch sensor) this is recognized as the zero state.  When I touch another person, the LED lights (but only if I ground the circuit to earth – does not work when no external ground is provided).  I suspect that without earth ground, the capacitance difference between the two people is too minimal to be recognized.

So my question is, if there is a way to alter the circuit to recognize the difference of capacitance between two people? Either through an "artificial earth" or through some added component such as capacitor.  The idea is to be portable and wearable.

Comment: I tried also attaching a separate battery and it's ground to my body, it does not help. Was trying to think out of the box!

Comment: Don't comment on your own post. Edit the post and put the details in there.

Comment: Your talking about a "mass" detector which uses high-frequency plates to detect objects over a given mass or close proximity. Similar to a capacitive touch screen on a smart-phone, but is a single metal plate or foil. Search for "Capacitive Sensors".